# Writing a system of differential equations with the given arbitrary reactions

Tags: kinetics

We have the following elementary reactions:
\begin{align}
&\overset{k_1}{\longrightarrow}A\overset{k_2}{\longrightarrow}{B+C}\\
&C \overset{k_4}{\longrightarrow} 2D \overset{k_5}{\longrightarrow}{C}\\
&B \overset{k_3}{\longrightarrow}\\
&D \overset{k_6}{\longrightarrow}
\end{align}
Let $\alpha(t), \beta(t), \gamma(t), \delta(t)$ denote the concentrations of $A, B, C, D$, respectively.
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\alpha(t) &= k_1 - k_2\alpha(t)\\[3pt]
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\beta(t) &= k_2\alpha(t) - k_3\beta(t)\\[3pt]
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\bigl(2\delta(t)\bigr) = 2\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\delta(t) &= k_4\gamma(t)-k_6\delta(t)^2 \quad \text{or} \quad \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\delta(t) = \frac{k_4}{2}\gamma(t) - \frac{k_6}{2}\delta(t)^2\\[3pt]
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\gamma(t) &= k_5\delta(t)^2 - k_4\gamma(t) + k_2\alpha(t)\\
\end{align}
Is my systems of equations correct?

Comment: No. There must be an instance of $\delta^2$. Also, where did the $\frac{d}{dt}(\beta + \gamma)$ thing come from?

Comment: Where is the law of mass action (I'm surprised you are invoking it for a non-equilibrium system)?

Comment: @IvanNeretin: It came from $A \overset{k_2}{\longrightarrow}B + C$?

Comment: @KarstenTheis: Oh no. I must have misunderstood what it meant. Sorry, my background is not in chemistry. I will remove it. Thanks!

Comment: @TheLastCipher Well, this reaction does not produce B **or** C; instead, each time it runs, it produces B **and** C, so it should be represented by two addends, **both** in $d\beta\over dt$ and $d\gamma\over dt$.

Comment: @IvanNeretin: What do you mean addend? I did write $\operatorname{\frac{d}{dt}}\beta(t) + \operatorname{\frac{d}{dt}}\gamma(t)$. Is that different? Thank you for your time answering.

Comment: @IvanNeretin: Also, should I have $\operatorname{\frac{d}{dt}}\gamma(t) = 2k_5\delta(t)^2 - k_4$, instead? Would love to know why it is suppose to be $\delta(t)^2$. Thank you very much!

Comment: I meant an addend in the RHS. On the left you shouldn't have any addends at all, just $d\beta\over dt$. As for $\delta^2$, well, it is because the law of mass action says so. We are probably going to apply it somewhere outside of its rightful domain, but then again, what choice do we have?

Comment: @IvanNeretin: I've simplified the equation with an addend on the left to be the equation to the left of the $\Leftrightarrow$ symbol. Maybe I should just remove the "unsimplified" form?

Comment: Maybe. Also, the $k_4$ term (the one _without_ the $\gamma$) seems wrong.

Comment: @IvanNeretin: Turns out they aren't the same. I have edited it now. My brain was stuck applying the rules on derivatives, but I now get where went wrong, conceptually. Thanks!

Comment: Now I don't like the derivative of $2\delta$. This is not how it works at all. You run the reaction once, you get **2**D for one C. The change in D is **twice greater** than that in C. The derivative of D should be greater, not smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\alpha(t) = k_1 - k_2\alpha(t)$ is correct.

Just to show you the way, here are the next equations:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\beta(t) &= k_2\alpha(t) - k_3\beta(t) \\
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\gamma(t) &= k_2\alpha(t) - k_4\gamma(t) + k_5\delta(t)^2 \\
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\delta(t) &= 2k_4\alpha(t) - k_6\delta(t) - k_5\delta(t)^2 
\end{align}
$$

Comment: we are left with $2\operatorname{\frac{d}{dt}}\delta(t) = k_4\gamma(t) - 2k_6 - k_5\delta(t)^2 \overset{equivalently}{\Longleftrightarrow} \operatorname{\frac{d}{dt}}\delta(t) = \frac{k_4}{2}\gamma(t) - k_6 - \frac{k_5}{2}\delta(t)^2$?

Comment: I appended the last equation from your another answer and cleaned up syntax a little. Please note there is a gray *edit* button on the bottom of the posts, which allows to commit changes to the Q&As, which is a preferred way over adding a new post if the addition is marginal. Also, please avoid breaking math expressions in the middle with dollar signs for no reason: `$x + y$` is correct, `$x$ + $y$` is wrong. Math operators are usually typed in upright typeface to avoid confusion with variables.

Comment: @Maurice: Why the $2k_4\alpha(t)$ term on the rate of change of $\delta(t)$?